# Mocking Room database in kotlin for android testcase throws error

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to write testcase for room database in kotlin for Android.
With below implementation, error occurs

DummyDatabase.kt

```
    internal abstract class DummyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: DummyDatabase ? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): DummyDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    DummyDatabase::class.java,
                    "db_name.db"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Method getWritableDatabase in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getWritableDatabase in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java)


  public void update(final ComplicationRoutine complicationRoutine) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
```

How to create mock for SQLiteOpenHelper in Room Database?

Comment: room has a specific dependency for testing, isn't it ? isn't there an in memory room db you can try ?

Comment: Room database makes use of SupportSQLiteOpenHelper, then why would error for SQLiteOpenHelper occurrs?